# Add Unity's Standard (Roughness) shader properties to custom shader?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a custom shader that is used to blend two materials easily. How do I include properties such as Normal map and emission properties and other properties as well from Unity's Standard (Roughness) shader?

```
Shader "Myshaders/ChangeMaterial" {
    Properties {
        _Tint ("Tint Color", Color) = (.9, .9, .9, 1.0)
        _TexMat1 ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _TexMat2 ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Blend ("Blend", Range(0.0,1.0)) = 0.0
    }

    Category {
        ZWrite On
        Alphatest Greater 0
        Tags {Queue=Transparent}
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ColorMask RGB
    SubShader {
        Pass {

            Material {
                Diffuse [_Tint]
                Ambient [_Tint]
            }
            Lighting On

            SetTexture [_TexMat1] { combine texture }
            SetTexture [_TexMat2] { constantColor (0,0,0,[_Blend]) combine texture lerp(constant) previous }
            SetTexture [_TexMat2] { combine previous +- primary, previous * primary }
        }
    }
    FallBack " Diffuse", 1
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are incorrectly using the legacy ShaderLab passes which do not apply to the Physically Based Rendering pipeline (contemporary) nor the scriptable rendering pipeline (bleeding edge).

You should get familiar with the built in shader code located at https://github.com/TwoTailsGames/Unity-Built-in-Shaders. Observe the `#include` statements located in the various passes here: https://github.com/TwoTailsGames/Unity-Built-in-Shaders/blob/master/DefaultResourcesExtra/Standard.shader